# LINQでXMLの取得するとき、親が同じものをまとめたい。

Tags: c#, xml, linq

お世話になっております。

下記のようなXMLがありまして、C#のLINQ機能で「てすと」と情報を取得したいです。

```
<cell>
    <p>すたっく</p>
    <run> て</run>
    <run> す</run>
    <p>すたっく</p>
    <run> と</run>
</cell>
```

下記のように取得してしまうと

```
doc.Descendants("run").Select(n => n.Value);
```

「て」「す」「と」がバラバラに取得されてしまいますので、JOINなどを使いいろいろ考えはしたのですが、
どうしてもうまくいかないです。

LINQでの取得時にうまくいく方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

---

複数のご回答誠にありがとうございます。

頂いた回答から工夫して挑戦したのですが、どうでもうまく行かず。
再度質問させていただきたいです。

下記のような状態から

```
<page>
    <cell>
        <p>
            <line>
                <run></run>
                <run>た</run>
                <run>ぬき</run>
            </line>
        </p>
    </cell>
    <cell>
       <p>
           <line>
                <run>き</run>
                <run>つ</run>
                <run>つき</run>
            </line>
        </p>
    </cell>
</page>
```

「たぬき」「きつつき」というワードを取得したいです。

申し訳ありません。もう一度アイディアのほういただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 追記されたXMLは不正ですので`XDocument`に読み込むと`XmlException`が発生しますが、どのように「うまく行かない」のでしょうか。エラーメッセージ等を追記してください。

Comment: エラーは出ないのですが、string.Concatですと取得したいデータの形でとれません。
「たぬききつつき」といった風にはとれるのですが、「たぬき」「きつつき」と取得したいです。

Comment: そのように動作するコードを回答したつもりですし、手元で試しても想定通りの出力が得られますが。データや実装に何か誤りがあるのでは。

Comment: 元質問は既に検索方法は解決されていて`"て"` `"す"` `"と"`という結果が得られている状況で、その結果の扱い方を問うものでした。対して追記された質問は検索方法そのものを問うもので、全く別件です。追記ではなく別途質問されるべきです。

Comment: 説明不足かつ不適切な質問の仕方をしてしまい申し訳ありません。。。
もう少しこちらで調査した上でわからなければ別途質問として上げたいと思います。
ご回答・レスありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XElement.Parent`でグループ化し、各グループを`string.Concat`などで結合すればよいのでは。

```
doc.Descendants("run")
    .GroupBy(n => n.Parent)
    .Select(g => string.Concat(g.Select(n => n.Value)))
```

### 追記

想定通りの結果が得られないとのことですので、上記コードの使用例を掲載しておきます。

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var xml = @"<page><cell>
    <p>
        <line>
            <run></run>
            <run>た</run>
            <run>ぬき</run>
        </line>
    </p>
</cell>
<cell>
    <p>
        <line>
            <run>き</run>
            <run>つ</run>
            <run>つき</run>
        </line>
    </p>
</cell></page>";

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        foreach (var s in doc.Descendants("run").GroupBy(n => n.Parent).Select(g => string.Concat(g.Select(n => n.Value))))
        {
            // たぬき/きつつきが出力される
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます！

Comment: 追記のほうにも回答していただきありがとうございます！

Comment: 「GroupBy(n => n.Parent)」が思いつきませんでした。本当にありがとうございます！